# как передать "заполненую" структуру в отдельный поток?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

В общем пытаюсь передать заполненую структуру в отдельный поток.
Вот код :

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

class TrimTram1
{
    struct Сanmsg_t
    {
        public uint id;
        public byte[] data;
        public byte len;
        public ushort flags;
        public uint ts;
    }

    static void Main(){

        // ---
        Thread t = new Thread (WriteY); // Начать новый поток , выполняющий WriteY().
        t.Start();

        // Одновременно чтото делать в главном потоке
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) Console.Write("x");

        // 1.заполняем структуру
        // 2.запускаем отдельный поток

        Сanmsg_t canmsg;

        byte[] array2 = new byte[] { 0xA1, 0x00, 0x48, 0xE8, 0x01 };
        canmsg.data = array2;
        canmsg.id = 0x123;
        canmsg.len = 8;

        Console.WriteLine("111111");
        Console.WriteLine("canmsg : canmsg.id {0}.", canmsg.id);
        Console.WriteLine("canmsg : canmsg.data {0}.", canmsg.data);
        Console.WriteLine("canmsg : canmsg.len {0}.", canmsg.len);
        Console.WriteLine("111111");
        //Thread t1 = new Thread(WrireZ(ref canmsg); так не работает
        Thread t1 = new Thread(WrireZ());
        t1.Start();
        // ---
    }

    static void WriteY()
    {
         for (int i=0; i<1000; i++ ) Console.Write("y");
    }

    // static void WrireZ(Сanmsg_t canmsg) так не работает
    static void WrireZ()
    {
        Сanmsg_t canmsg = new Сanmsg_t();
        //Сanmsg_t canmsg; так не работает 

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--------");
            Console.WriteLine("canmsg : canmsg.id {0}.", canmsg.id);
            Console.WriteLine("canmsg : canmsg.data {0}.", canmsg.data);
            Console.WriteLine("canmsg : canmsg.len {0}.", canmsg.len);
            Console.WriteLine("--------");
        }
    }
}
```

Вот вывод :

```
111111
canmsg : canmsg.id 291.
canmsg : canmsg.data System.Byte[].
canmsg : canmsg.len 8.
111111
--------
canmsg : canmsg.id 0.
canmsg : canmsg.data .
canmsg : canmsg.len 0.
--------
--------
canmsg : canmsg.id 0.
canmsg : canmsg.data .
canmsg : canmsg.len 0.
--------
--------
canmsg : canmsg.id 0.
canmsg : canmsg.data .
canmsg : canmsg.len 0.
--------
--------
canmsg : canmsg.id 0.
canmsg : canmsg.data .
canmsg : canmsg.len 0.
--------
....
```

не получается передать заполненную структуру, а как тогда передавать данные в поток который ещё не запущен ??

---

Также попробовал так :

```
    Thread myNewThread = new Thread(() => WrireZ(canmsg));
    myNewThread.Start();

    ...
    static void WrireZ(Сanmsg_t canmsg)
    ...
```

вот вывод :

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ mcs tehn4.cs 
tehn4.cs(78,54): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable `canmsg'
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Также так попробовал :

```
    var t = new Thread(() => WrireZ(canmsg));
    t.Start();

    ...
    static void WrireZ(Сanmsg_t canmsg)
    ...
```

вот вывод :

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ mcs tehn4.cs 
tehn4.cs(83,13): error CS0128: A local variable named `t' is already defined in this scope
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

не понимаю, что не так ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ответ дали тут :3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1095759/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%A1)

Вот ответ:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

class TrimTram1
{
    struct Сanmsg_t
    {
        public uint id;
        public byte[] data;
        public byte len;
        public ushort flags;
        public uint ts;
    }

    static void Main(){

        // ---
        Thread t = new Thread (WriteY); // Начать новый поток, выполняющий WriteY().
        t.Start();

        // Одновременно чтото делать в главном потоке
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) Console.Write("x");

        // 1.заполняем структуру
        // 2.запускаем отдельный поток

        Сanmsg_t canmsg = new Сanmsg_t();

        byte[] array2 = new byte[] { 0xA1, 0x00, 0x48, 0xE8, 0x01 };
        canmsg.data = array2;
        canmsg.id = 0x123;
        canmsg.len = 8;

        Console.WriteLine("111111");
        Console.WriteLine("canmsg : canmsg.id {0}.", canmsg.id);
        Console.WriteLine("canmsg : canmsg.data {0}.", canmsg.data);
        Console.WriteLine("canmsg : canmsg.len {0}.", canmsg.len);
        Console.WriteLine("111111");
        //Thread t1 = new Thread(WrireZ(ref canmsg); так не работает
        new Thread(() => WrireZ(ref canmsg)).Start();

        // ---
    }

    static void WriteY()
    {
         for (int i=0; i<1000; i++ ) Console.Write("y");
    }

    static void WrireZ(ref Сanmsg_t canmsg)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--------");
            Console.WriteLine("canmsg : canmsg.id {0}.", canmsg.id);
            Console.WriteLine("canmsg : canmsg.data {0}.", canmsg.data);
            Console.WriteLine("canmsg : canmsg.len {0}.", canmsg.len);
            Console.WriteLine("--------");
        }
    }
}
```

По сути поменял три строки :

```
Сanmsg_t canmsg = new Сanmsg_t();
...
new Thread(() => WrireZ(ref canmsg)).Start();
...
static void WrireZ(ref Сanmsg_t canmsg)
...
```