# передача структуры в поток, в С#

Tags: c#

Теоретический вопрос, по сему без кода.

С толкнулся с таким интересным явлением что , невозможно передать заполненную структуру в отдельный поток.
Перелистал все книги и спросил у интернета.

***Запустить поток пожалуйста, передать одну переменную(int ... string) бери используй лямбда выражения дорогой, НО структуру передать не возможно.***

Можно передать структуру в класс а сам класс объявить в запущенном потоке и работать с ним.

---

**структура =| поток**

**структура => класс => поток**

**Выходит только так :3**

Так ли это ? Правильно ли я размышляю ??

Comment: Не совсем понятно что подразумевается под передачей структуры в поток, лучше все-таки с кодом

Comment: Эмм. нет? `Test test = new Test(10, 20); Task.Run(() => { Console.WriteLine($"{test.a}, {test.b}"); });` Вывод в консоль `10, 20`. Поэтому лучше добавьте конкретики и возможно кода, который бы демонстрировал проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку код в комментариях вставлять неудобно, то отставлю его ответом. Если вы вдруг обновите вопрос, то либо удалю этот ответ, либо подправлю его под новые требования.

---

Структура особо не отличается от класса, только хранится по другому и передается из-за этого не по ссылке, а по значению. Поэтому при передаче её в поток не должно быть никаких проблем. Можно даже устроить драку между потоками за неё.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    struct Test {
        public string name;
        public int a;
        public int b;

        public Test(string name, int a, int b) {
            this.name = name;
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        public string Display()
        {
            return $"{name}, {a}, {b}";
        } 
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test test = new Test("", 10, 20);

            new Thread(() => RunThread(500, "thread 1", ref test)).Start();
            new Thread(() => RunThread(700, "thread 2", ref test)).Start();
            new Thread(() => RunThread(900, "thread 3", ref test)).Start();

            while (true) {
                Console.WriteLine(test.Display());
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        public static void RunThread(int delay, string name, ref Test test)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(delay);
                Console.WriteLine("Change struct from " + test.Display());
                test.name = name;
                test.a = rand.Next(0, 100);
                test.b = rand.Next(0, 100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```